# qooxdoo qx.ui.mobile.form.NumberField does not support HTML5 step number format

Tags: qooxdoo

In the documentation for the qooxdoo mobile NumberField there is described that the NumberField is using the HTML5 input element. In HTML5 the step size for an input is a number, however in qooxdoo the step is an integer. Which means that a step size of 0.1 is not possible in qooxdoo while this is supported on HTML5. Is this a bug and wrong implementation of qooxdoo or are there valid reasons for this qooxdoo implementation. The same question I have for the mobile Slider field. Also there I expect a stepSize containing a decimal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the two mentioned widgets.

For the NumberField, I don't see a reason why it should be an integer as we only forward the data to the DOM. So changing that to number would be worth a bug report and should not be much effort.

The slider does not use the HTML5 range input type so it a custom qooxdoo implementation. Bug a quick check of the code did not show any bigger issues why the steps in the slider should not be a floating point number as well.

You can open up issues on the [qooxdoo bugzilla](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/) and request a change for that.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have created the 2 issues in qooxdoo bugzilla.